# How can set cursor: hand with GWT: label

Tags: gwt, label, mouse-cursor

I'd like to set a mouse listener to my Label so that I can change the cursor to a HAND_CURSOR when the user places their mouse over a label.

```
 <g:Label text="Overview" styleName="left_menu_title" ui:field="lb_overview"/>
```

I tried to set style css "cursor: hand;" for this Label, but when run, all attribute cursor were replaced.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean css "cursor:pointer"?

Comment: I tried "cursor: point" and "cursor: hand" but it was still replaced

Comment: add `cursor: pointer !important;` to force your CSS style if something else is overwriting it.

Comment: That's because there is no such cursor like `point` or `hand` defined in the CSS standard. The correct term to use is `pointer`, as Chris showed in his answer. You can see a list of valid CSS cursor values here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Thanks Strelok and Abdullah, I changed css to cursor: pointer !important; and it worked.

Answer (score 19):

The answer provided by *user1557828* will in fact cause the Label to show the cursor when the mouse is over it, but there is a simpler way to achieve the same result:

```
Label testLabel = new Label("Text Goes Here);
testLabel.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);
```

This will set the cursor at instantiation and the style will persist. It is not necessary to re-apply the style each time the mouse moves over the label.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do it would be:

```
.left_menu_title {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

and

```
<g:Label text="Overview" styleName="{style.left_menu_title}" ui:field="lb_overview"/>
```

Comment: As I said all attribute of cursor was replaced. Even "cursor: point;" "cursor: hand;"

Comment: added label styling rule. You weren't declaring it right for the label.

Comment: You should probably use `addStylesNames` rather than `styleName`, but that's independent from the issue discussed here; just a FYI.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed it by using "cursor: pointer !important;"

Answer (score 2):

You have only to do the following :

```
.left_menu_title {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you want a code to do other thing than set cursor to pointer :

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Cursor;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOverEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseOverHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;

...
...
...


 final Label testLabel = new Label();
 testLabel.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {     
        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
             testLabel.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);   

            //TODO: any thing you want      
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
where to this one..
Label testLabel = new Label("Text Goes Here);
testLabel.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER); 

in my code provided below..

 {
   xtype:'label',
   text:'testLabel',
   id:'cancel1',
   Label testLabel = new Label("Text Goes Here);  
   testLabel.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER); 
   listeners : {
   render : function(d) {
   d.getEl().on('click', function(){ this.fireEvent('click', d); }, d);
}
}

}
```

Comment: i have tried this in my code but it is not working plz give me the appropriate answer where to put it in my code...